# How to post value in multiple textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had here a ajax function for posting data in pr field. What I need to do is post all the value base on pr# in my database. How I can post the other data in different textboxes using ajax? Below is my database structure and image and codes. Any help will be appreciate.

**Pr Database Details Structure**

```
Pr #  | Supplier  | Receipt #  | Receiver  |
--------------------------------------------
321-B | Villman   | 312312331  | John      |
556-B | Dockers   | 903232317  | William   |
```

Here's my Code

**index.php**

```
<select id="pr">
<?php ... ?>
</select>

<input id="pr_num">
<input id="supplier">
<input id="receipt">
<input id="receiver">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[id="pr"]').change(function()
{
var prjt_code = $("#pr").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data :"pr_code="+pr_code,
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
   success:function(data){
  //alert(data);
    $('#pr_num').val(data);
   }
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pr_code'])) {
$pr_code= $_POST['pr_code'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pr_table WHERE pr='$pr_code'");

while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $code = $row['pr'];
  }
echo $code;
}
?>
```

Comment: you're only ever going to be returning one value from your ajax. you need to either concat each row onto the last with a delimiter to separate them, or put them all into an array and json_encode it for sending back

Comment: `$(".input-selector").val( 'value-to-set' );` should do it.

Comment: u want to pass all option value of select tag in ajax?

Comment: @ElefantPhace How I can do that? Can you show me please?

Comment: @MayurKukadiya Yah, All of the details per PR# post into the designated inputs. Supplier name to textbox of supplier and so on

Comment: var values = $.map($('#t_name_lang option'), function(e) { return e.value; });

values.join(',');   u can get comaa separated option values and this value pass through ajax call and php side u can explode by comma and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class name for the `pr_num` textbox. let's say

```
<input type="text" id="pr_num" class="pr_num_class"/>
```

Then to iterate the textboxes use jQuery's `.each()` function

```
$(".pr_num_class").each(function(){
    $(this).val("//your text here");
})
```